# Saving a proces steps to the global variable

Tags: php

I know that store some class data to the global variable is a bad idea for many reasons.

What if I have a huge code where I want to log some processes for a many classes and do not want to use some created file.

My approach

```
$log = [];

addLog($t) {
     global $log[] = $t;
}



class Foo
{
    function doStuff()
    {
        /// some stuff
        addLog('diong stuff')
    }
}

class Foo2
{
    function doStuff()
    {
        /// some stuff
        addLog('doing some other stuff')
    }
}

$Foo = new Foo();
$Foo2 = new Foo2();


$Foo->doStuff();
$Foo2->doStuff();
$Foo->doStuff();
$Foo2->doStuff();


        /// at the end i hve 20MB of $log datas to work with
print_r($log);
```

I know this is far away from optimal. 
**What solution is a best practise?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to have a separate logger class, that's given to objects that need logging via dependency injection.

Here's a rudimentary example based on your code: https://3v4l.org/0WpGZ

I'd say a good practice is to not have *mutable* static variables. If you're ever going to write unit tests for your code, static variables end up being a pain.

Comment: Hi thx. And how can i pass own vars to the constructor of Foo2 ?
https://3v4l.org/AIgIP

Comment: @Martin: Override the constructor and call parent, like https://3v4l.org/BdNJ4. If it gets cumbersome to pass logger via constructor, you can always have a setter method for it, like https://3v4l.org/fMVbB.

Answer (score 1):

Use satic Class to call it wherever in your code.

I added a limit counter, to flush the logs stack whenever it reaches this limit.
set it to 0 to disable this functionality.

```
<?php
    class LogStack{
        static $maxLogs = 1000;

        static $logsCount = 0;

        static $stack = [];

        public static function addLog($log, $tag = "log"){
            $stack[$tag][] = $log;
            if(static::$maxLogs !== 0 && (++static::$logsCount) == static::$maxLogs){
                //Save your logs
                static::saveLogs();
            }
        }

       public static function saveLogs(){
            //Save logs on your persistent storage
            //Dont forget to empty the stack and reset the counter
            //static::$logs = [];
            //static $logsCount = 0;
        }
    }


    class Foo
    { 

        function doStuff()
        {
            /// will save in default logs (log tag)
            $this->addLog('diong stuff');
        }
    }

    class Foo2
    { 

        function doStuff()
        {
            /// will save in foo2 logs (foo2 tag)
            LogStack::addLog('doing some other stuff', 'foo2');
        }
    }
```

And, in the end of your script, call the saving method to save the remaining logs

```
<?php
    LogStack::saveLogs();
```

Comment: hi thanks. But this still does not operate with one $stack variable for whole code, or can I call $stack at the end of all Foo and Foo2 functions?
If i understand, you calculate with saving to some storage as a file or DB. But i want to avoid it, it is too slow, i have a lot of operations and i want to save all to one log file at the end at once.

Comment: I updated the answer, All you have to do is set the maxLogs to 0 and call the saving method in the end of your script to save the logs